# React navigation pushes multiple screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm tryin to navigate with simple navigation on my React native project. When navigation to screen A to B then goin back with android back button, next time when navigation A to B then B to C. React navigator pushes multiple C screens . Any idea would be great. Cheers.

```
  //stack navigator 
  const StackScreense = StackNavigator({
    A: { screen: A},
    B: { screen: B},
    C: { screen: C},
   }, {
      initialRouteName: 'A',
      navigationOptions:{ header: null},
      initialRouteParams: { status: ' ' }
    });
  //navigation
  this.props.navigation.navigate('B');

  this.props.navigation.navigate('C', {
      params
    });
```

Comment: If you are adding navigation on a button, and press buttons more than once then , mutiple screens get pushed. Do you want a solution for that or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: it was a socket.io related thing. Thanks anyways. I'm using a timeout logic with state for multiple button press tho. What is ur solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was navigating with socket.io forgot to unmount listeners. That was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically you can use the following solution, to check if the *next screen routeName* is **not similar** to the *previous screen routeName*, provided that you are calling the `NAVIGATE` action

Here's the middleware for that

```
const navigateOnce = getStateForAction => (action, state) => {
  const { type, routeName } = action
  return state &&
    type === NavigationActions.NAVIGATE &&
    routeName === state.routes[state.routes.length - 1].routeName
    ? null
    : getStateForAction(action, state)
}
```

**Usage**

```
YourStackRouter.router.getStateForAction = navigateOnce(
  YourStackRouter.router.getStateForAction
)
```